# Blender add rough/random surface

Tags: modifiers

I took a long break from blender recently, and I'm having the hardest time remembering the modifier **that added random rotations to vertices.**

All that I can find online is using the Displace modifier with a texture. But I'm **100%** sure I didn't use that when I created this old model (picture below).

[image: Modifier result that I'm searching for]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out it didn't have to do anything with modifiers but in fact it was just **the fractal setting when subdividing**

Answer (score 12):

You probably think of using Proportional Editing with Random Editing Falloff.[image]